# Visual Studio 2013 does not import Linq namespace

Tags: xml, linq, f#

I am trying to use XDocument class in F# and import the namespace.

> open System.Xml.Linq

But the compiler complain, that the namespace linq is not defined.
[image]

The assembly System.Xml.Linq is also added.

[image]

I also load the library into interactive windows with:

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq" ;;
```

What do I wrong?

Comment: Which framework version is your project targeting?

Comment: Dot net framework 4.5

Comment: Looks similar to [Missing namespace while running F# script from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20959852/205233) ... in any case it's crucial that your problem occurs in a fsx script rather than fs code file.

Comment: yes i am running as fsx script.

Comment: You might try adding a reference to `System.Linq` as well.

Answer (score 0):

According to this [MSDN entry](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.extensions%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the assembly 'System.Xml.XDocument.dll' might also be required.

Comment: As you can see on the picture, I did import `System.Xml`.

Comment: Yes, but aren't 'System.Xml.dll' and 'System.Xml.XDocument.dll' different assemblies?

Comment: I can not find System.Xml.XDocument.dll

Comment: On my machine, it is located in `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319`.

Answer (score 0):

Put the string

```
#r "System.Xml.Linq"
```

before your open statements in F# script